# Can you add +$ for gifts in dev demon subscriptions?

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

> Conditionals - This allows customer information to increase or decrease the price of your subscription. For example the customer is in Canada and you are shipping a product to the customer each month. This would allow for an additional conditional charge if the customer chooses Canada in their customer information.

This seems limited to certain customer fields, like country or state, but is there any way to have a field 'tick to add this as a gift' +$ as part of a subscription?

Comment: Agreed, This would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have to do this in the template and use a form field to send the price. We are working on an improved system that will work more like attributes in shopping carts.

Comment: Brad, any idea when the next version will be out.  This request above would be very helpful.